# How to run more than one service simultaneously in android without any conflict?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to run two AsyncTasks at the same time. However, only the first gets executed. And no data returned from second service. When refresh it second time I get data from service hoe to resolve the issue??
Here is my code

```
new MyClass().execute("Main");
```

**> Class is**

```
private class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
```

**> here i am using pre post and do in background methods**

```
}
```

Comment: You should be able to execute them a bunch of times. I perform about 20 of them in a couple of seconds. Can you post the code where you're trying to execute them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This allows for parallel execution on all android versions with API 4+ (Android 1.6+):**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) // API 11

void startMyTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    else
        asyncTask.execute(params);
}
```

Comment: use  above code in place of new MyClass().execute("Main");